# Google Places API URL returning error

Tags: google-maps

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-35.3419983,149.108&radius=8000&types=school&name=Malkara%20School&sensor=true&key=MY_KEY

I am preparing above link through my program in java and retriving details about the places. However i am encountering error. See the code below.

```
Line 1 : URL url = new URL(theUrl);
Line 2 : URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
Line 3 : BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()), 8);
```

Line 3 result in error.And surprising part is that Exception e is null !!!

I am using ADT bundle.

Any help is highly appreciated.

regards,

--Pankaj

Comment: Use debug statements at each step, verify that everything is correct before you reach line 3 and let us know.

Comment: Yes everything is correct. I copy and paste URL in browser and can see json results is returned.

Comment: I removed the &name from the URL and it started working!!! The same URL worked in browser. Any clues why &name is not working through program.??